# How to filtering data with multiple criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, filtering

Hello could you please help with this. I'm using asp.net mvc 5 application, my home view has 2 parts. One where the data shown and the other which filters this data. For now I just show all my data without filtering. I've read few tutorials, but they use fewer properties for filtering. In my case I have really large data for filtering (more than 10 properties).

So I've found recommendation to use viewmodel as the parameter for filter, but there weren't any suggestions how to implement view and controller.

I've made some preparation for this work, I've took all the logic from the controller and created separate class called business logic and put there following code:

```
public IQueryable<ModelDTO> GetData(FilterViewModel filter)
{
    var main = (from data in db.Table
                    // Other commands
                select new
                {
                    data.Id,
                    data.Title,
                    data.Creteria1,
                    data.Creteria2,
                    // Other fields
                }).ToList();

    // Other logic

    if (filter != null)
    {
        // TODO develop the filter logic
        if (filter.Creteria1.HasValue)
        {
            main = main.Where(x => x.Creteria1 == filter.Creteria1);
        }
        if (filter.Creteria2.HasValue)
        {
            main = main.Where(x => x.Creteria2 == filter.Creteria2);
        }
        // etc.
    }

    return main.AsQueryable();
}

My controller looks like this:

public ActionResult Index(FilterViewModel f)
{
    var b = new BusinessLogic();
    var m = b.GetData(f);
    return View(m);
}
```

In my view I've implemented html forms with all fields, how to map it to FilterViewModel?

I need whenever user change fields in filter form and hit submit button to filter data.

I need to have by default filled FilterViewModel, so initially it will loads all the data.

Also in my view I'm using DTOModel, so I can't just my FilterViewModel.

Comment: you have one form right having multiple textbox exa. for filtering , just set your input type `name` attribute same as your `FilterViewModel` class property then whenever you submit your form it will fill into your model. also you check your querystring from `Request`

Comment: You should not convert to list at first. If query returns a big amount data, the performance will be bad.